# Keep WordPress (local and remote) in sync

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Keeping a local and remote WordPress installation in sync is no easy feat. Syncing the file structure is no problem, but keeping the databases in sync seems to be the real obstacle. Is there a reliable way to keep a local WordPress installation in sync with a remote installation, including the database? Using a build script seems to be a viable approach, but I was wondering if there is a more obvious approach that I overlooked.

Comment: I personally use third party tool for database sync, file sync is done by simple FTP file upload. If you want to use a GUI tool I can give you the link.

Comment: Are you local and remote databases identical? In other words, do you use the same web address for both installations?

Comment: The databases are identical, of course the local and remote address are not, this is the only difference.

Comment: That is correct. However, that subtle difference determines whether the WordPress installation works properly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping DBs in sync is not a trivial task. Importing and overwriting the local DB with the live DB every x number of days seems like a logical approach if you don't mind losing local changes.

Keeping the codebase in sync should be achievable with any D/VCS (git, subversion) or even good ol' rsync

Comment: The codebase is not the issue for me. The databases is not only a problem in terms of syncing, but also because some data is platform specific, for example, the database credentials and the site address of the WordPress installation. In other words, the databases differ slightly (and so does the config.php file).

Comment: Do you mean just the login credentials for the DB or do you mean usernames and passwords stored in the DB?

Comment: Both. The login credentials contained in config.php differ and the web address is different for the local and remote installation.